# OfficeThemes.css file not being regenerated

Tags: office-js

I'm following the [guidelines here](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/powerpoint/use-document-themes-in-your-powerpoint-add-ins?product=excel) to change the styles of my task pane based upon the current Office theme.  For reference, I'm building an Excel Add-in.

In my `.html` page that is being loaded in the pane, I have included the following script tag:

```
<link href="[local_path_to_OfficeThemes.css]" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Additionally, I populated the script tag with the CSS given in the guidelines linked to above, and confirmed that the styles were being applied properly.

Finally, I changed the Excel theme (Page Layout > Themes), and refreshed my Add-in... expecting to see a new color palette reflected in the pane.  However, despite following these guidelines exactly, line-by-line, the CSS file does not seem to regenerate (and consequently, the task pane colors do not change) when Excel theme is changed in Page Layout > Themes.  Does anyone know how I can debug this?

Comment: You are required to post your markup here. [mcve]

Comment: I'll post my code... there's almost no markup however.  Edited above.

Comment: That is not anything useful in any way. See the link I provided. We need to duplicate your efforts and see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office document themes is supported only for PowerPoint, so It won't work on Excel. If you'd like to see it extended to Excel, please got to [Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and suggest it. (Check first to see if someone already has and, if so, vote up the existing suggestion.)